# Computing tight lower bound on $P(X = 0)$, given first $k$ moments of non-negative integer random variable $X$

Tags: probability

So given the first and second moments of a non-negative integer random variable $X$, if $E(X) < 1$, this forces $P(X = 0) > 0$ although as pointed out in the comments, the tight lower bound for $P(X = 0)$ is $1 - E(X)$ regardless of the given value of $E(X^2)$. But what if we are given the first $k$ moments for $k > 2$? What would the formula or algorithm be for computing the tight lower bound on $P(X = 0)$ in terms of the moments? I strongly suspect that the answer is no longer $1 - E(X)$ for $k > 2$, i.e. the higher moments affect the bound.

Comment: How does $k=2$ work? For any fixed $E(X)>1$, I can push $E(X^2)$ as high as I want simply by concentrating $X$ on $\{1,K\}$ - 2 parameters $(K,p)$, two equations ($E(X)$, $E(X^2)$). Sure, there are some "integer" issues at hand, but it fails the general stated principle.

Comment: @A.S. You're right I didn't mean "and/or", because you need $E(X) \leq 1$ to conclude anything like you noticed. I'll edit. Also I'll double-check my solution for $k = 2$ and post it for completeness.

Comment: You know that $P(X=0)\ge 1-E(x)$ but nothing more than that. Even for $k=2$, you can consider $X$ concentrated on $\{0,1,K\}$ to achieve any desired variance while keeping the same $E(X)<1$ and making $P(X=0)$ arbitrarily close to $1-E(X)$ - just take a $B(E(X))$ and split off a tiny mass all the way to $K$ with minimal effect on $E(X)$ and considerable effect on $E(X^2)$

Comment: @A.S. You're right again, I finally managed to show my algorithmic solution will run forever and converge to $1 - E(X)$. Will update question again. Actually I think this makes it more interesting because for $k > 2$ I strongly suspect the higher moments can affect the bound, unlike $k = 2$.

Comment: How does $k>2$ make a difference? You can still split off some tiny mass to a REALLY high $K_{k-1}$ to satisfy $k$th moment condition and slightly larger mass to smaller $K_{t-1}$ to satisfy $t$th moment.

Comment: Think of it in the following terms: you start with all mass at 0. Then you split some mass to satisfy the first moment condition ($E(X)<1$). Then you split a tiny bit more to satisfy the second moment, then split more to satisfy the third and so on. There might be some degenerate combinations of moment conditions, but in general formation it could push $P(X=0)$ as close to $1-E(X)$ as you like.

Comment: @A.S. I don't think it works anymore for $k = 3$ for example because if, say, you put a mass at $X \geq n$ in order to partially satisfy the second moment by contributing non-negligible $C$ to it then you will have $E(X^3) \geq n C$. So for $k = 3$ it seems you can't choose $n$ arbitrarily large and so you can't make the probability $P(X > 1)$  arbitrarily small like the $k = 2$ case.

Comment: @A.S. The question was motivated by Putnam 2014 question A4, where they state $E(X) = 1, E(X^2) = 2, E(X^3) = 5$ and they ask for the smallest possible value of $P(X = 0)$. It seems unlikely the answer is $0$.

Comment: This is what I meant by "integer issues"/non-general position. You can ever-so-slightly perturb the values to get $P(X=0)=0$.

Comment: Solution to Putnam's problem: Let $f(x)$ be generating function of $p_n=P(X=n)$. Then $f^{(i)}(1)=E(X)_i(=1 \text{ for } i\le 3)$ and by Taylor's theorem $$P(X=0)=f(0)=\sum_{i=0}^3 (-1)^i\frac{f^{(i)}(1)}{i!}+\frac{f^{(4)}(c)}{4!}\ge \frac 1 3$$ and is achieved for $p_n=0$ for $n\ge 4$ (and $(p_0,p_1,p_2,p_3)=(\frac 1 3, \frac 1 2,0,\frac 1 6)$). This approach can be generalized.